# What is returned by an INSERT ON DUPLICATE statement?

Tags: postgresql, insert-update

In Postgresql, when inserting rows with an `on conflict` and a `returning` clause, what is returned? The row that was inserted? The row before insertion? What if no row was inserted?

Consider the following statement using `... on conflict do nothing returning ...`:

```sql
insert into test
values (:id, :name)
on conflict do nothing
returning id;
```

and the following statement `... on conflict (...) do update ... returning ...`:

```sql
insert into test
values (:id, :name)
on conflict (name) do update
set id = EXCLUDED.id + 10
returning id;
```

and assume both `id` and `name` columns to be unique. What will the above statements return?

Closely related, how could I find the ID of the existing row that causes a conflict?

PS: Yes, I could easily just try it out. In fact, that's what I did (see the answer). It's easy to make a wrong guess, hard to remember the answer and expensive to reproduce the experiment, so I thought this question would be useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

The `returning` clause always returns the information that was **written** to the table (i.e. inserted or updated). If no write occurred, no row will be returned.

As a consequence, if you want to obtain the id of the existing row that causes a conflict, you cannot use `on conflict do nothing`. Instead, you could use `on conflict (...) do update` with a dummy update to provoke a write that doesn't actually modify the contents of the existing row, like so:

```sql
insert into test
values (4, 'singleton')
on conflict (name) do update
set id = test.id -- force a write, but don't change anything
returning id;
```

Note however that this artificial write may still have undesirable side-effects, especially if triggers are in place. You'll also generate new tuples even if the data doesn't change.

Experimental proof:

```sql
drop table if exists test;
create table test (
    id int primary key,
    name text unique
);

insert into test
values (1, 'singleton');

select * from test;
-- +--+---------+
-- |id|name     |
-- +--+---------+
-- |1 |singleton|
-- +--+---------+

insert into test
values (2, 'singleton')
on conflict do nothing
returning id;
-- result: empty

insert into test
values (2, 'something else')
on conflict (name) do update
    set id = EXCLUDED.id + 10
returning id;
-- result:
-- +--+
-- |id|
-- +--+
-- |2 |
-- +--+

insert into test
values (3, 'singleton')
on conflict (name) do update
set id = EXCLUDED.id + 10
returning id;
-- result:
-- +--+
-- |id|
-- +--+
-- |13|
-- +--+

insert into test
values (4, 'singleton')
on conflict (name) do update
set id = test.id
returning id;
-- result:
-- +--+
-- |id|
-- +--+
-- |13|
-- +--+

select * from test;
-- result:
-- +--+--------------+
-- |id|name          |
-- +--+--------------+
-- |2 |something else|
-- |13|singleton     |
-- +--+--------------+
```